# Connection via SSH-Tunnel to local MongoDB can't be established

Tags: mongodb, ssh-tunnel

I do have installed mongodb at my Server.
I can connect via CLI straight from the server, and I can connect the SSH-Tunnel to the server (via NoSQLBooster).

But what not work is to connect the MongoDB via SSH-Tunnel.
Here are the output of the Connection:

[image: NoSQLBooster Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out, that the issue was in the SSH Configuration at my Server.

At least you MUST allow TCPForwarding to be able to connect to MongoDB via SSH-Tunnel.

So I comment out those both lines and everything work as expected:

```
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

After that restart your SSH-Service, and connection should established.